# Saving model fields in admin interface in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

My problem is with editing model fields in admin interface. The model has encrypted keys and I have already done a form for a user who has logged in can edit their model/keys in the website.

Now, I want to have admin be possible to edit these same keys too in the admin interface. This requires that **the keys has to be encrypted first before saving them** in the database.

I have my model in admin interface with code in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(CryptedKeysModel)
```

I get shown a encrypted fields now, but if I edit any field, it isn't encrypted. I do the encryption in the views when it's showed for user in website, but **where I should do the encryption, when I'm saving fields in admin interface?** I guess in the models.py (?)

Comment: You should be doing this in the [`save` method of the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [ModelAdmin.save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #Encript fields values
        super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Seems what I searched. I want to get different code for each saved field, so how can I get one field in save_model-function? Like if I have fields keyX and keyY.

Comment: `obj.keyX` or `form.cleaned_data['keyX']`, it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's nice to be able to add custom code to the save method of objects in the Django Admin. So, when editing an object on the Admin object detail page (change form), adding the following method override to your ModelAdmin in admin.py will allow you to add custom code to the save function.

In admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # custom stuff here
        obj.save()
```